# How could I throw an InvalidOperationException if I tried running a method twice in a row?

Tags: c#, class, exception

**This is my class here.  How would I make it throw an InvalidOperationException if I tried running StartWatch twice in a row in main, before running StopTheWatch? **

```
    public void StartWatch(DateTime start)
    {
        _start = start;

    }

    public void StopTheWatch(DateTime stop)
    {
        _stop = stop;
        var timeSpan = _stop - _start;
        var minutes = timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
        _totalTime += minutes;

    }

    public double Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return _totalTime;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I'm very new at this as you might tell.

Comment: It is better that you share your whole class and not just part of it

Answer (score 1):

Add a class member:

bool _running = false;

Change your StartWatch method to:

```
public void StartWatch(DateTime start)
{
    if (_running)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    
    _running = true;
    _start = start;
}
```

Then add _running = false; in your StopTheWatch method.
Isn't thread safe though. In that case you could use lock, ManualResetEvent, etc.
But that's for another question :)